# In Java how does one convert from declared int value then print out decimal approximations

Tags: java, int, decimal

This is to say that the int are put into a System.out.println(); method that divides them up. But the value is a whole number, how does one take what's outputted as a whole number and get a decimal value from the declare int values?

Thank you

Comment: Can't understand what the problem is. Would please provide some code about what you really gonna do?

Comment: I just wanted the integers I declared to go from integers in the declaration/initialization in the first part of my code then once it prints I wanted those ints to be converted to decimals. I solved through Rogues help. I just slapped a double in front of every int in the parentheses of System.out.print(); but now my problem is having a condition met where sometimes that decimal is either positive of negative. I can set up the logic fine. But any time I put a negative inside the print(); it throws off the conversion, and when I put "-" in there it turns everything into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's a couple ways, but you just cast it:

```
int myInt = 42;
System.out.println((double) myInt);
//Formatter
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", (double) myInt); //control output, e.g. 2 decimal places
```

Comment: Thank you thank you! that worked. Now my problem is I want to print the decimal but one condition if the user picks needs to print positive the other negative. I just want to slap the negative out front. But every time I do that the rest of the (double)int gets converted into a string. I tried putting it "-" then I just slapped on a negative sign but that through off the conversion. How does one get around that?

Comment: why not just multiply by `-1`?

Comment: This is true. Derp moment!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you have two integer values and you want to merge them to become one number, with one of the 2 integers in the decimal part?

Well, if that is your question, then you can solve it by a simple while loop.

```
double wholePart = (double) userInput;
double decimalPart = (double) userInput;

while(Math.abs(decimalPart)>=1)
decimalPart /= 10;

System.out.print(Math.sign(decimalPart * wholePart) (Math.abs(wholePart) + Math.abs(decimalPart)));
```

Edit2: Using absolute values

Comment: I was able to convert the int to a double from the original declaration and initialization by simply placing double next to every int inside the parentheses of System.out.println();. Now my problem is having a condition met where it will print negative output and positive output of that decimal, depending on what option the user chooses. But every time I put a negative in the parentheses it outputs the wrong conversation. Then when I put "-" it turns everything into a string. Any idea around that?

Comment: I edited the post to work with negative decimal parts.

If you want to try making something negative, I suggest multiplying it by -1

Comment: I did another edit and now it should work flawlessly with negative numbers, but if both ints are negative then the result will be positive.

Comment: Multiplying it by -1 I should have realized honestly. Very new to Java programming, as you might have guessed. Thanks for the tips! Have not used the math import yet. But this is great advice!

Comment: Would it not just be quicker to `Double.parseDouble(wholePart + "." + decimalPart);`?

Comment: @Rogue that should work but I'm not sure how that handles negative values for decimalPart

Comment: It wouldn't, but you could do a little conditional logic vs. a bunch of repeated division.